# Ошибка исполнения. Проблема с векторами. c++

Tags: c++, vector

Я пытаюсь создать вектор состоящий из векторов целых чисел, где в каждом из N элементов, есть три различных элемента. При запуске данного кода выходит следующая ошибка.

> Ошибка исполнения, код возврата -1073741819

```
int main() {
   int N;
   int a, b , c;
   cin >> N;
   vector<vector<int>> v;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      cin >> a >> b >> c;
      v[i][1] = a;
      v[i][2] = b;
      v[i][3] = c;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы даже сделал так:

```
int main() {
   int N;
   cin >> N;
   vector<vector<int>> v(N,vector<int>(4));
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       cin >> v[i][1] >> v[i][2] >> v[i][3];
   }
}
```

Надеюсь, вы помните, что нумерация элементов вектора идет с нуля, и отсутствие у вас присвоения `v[i][0]` не ошибка, и вы знаете, что делаете...

Answer (score 6):

конечно  будет ошибка. Потому что вектора имеют нулевой размер.

И есть два способа исправить

```
int main() {
 int N;
 int a, b , c;
 cin >> N;
 vector<vector<int>> v;
 v.resize(N);
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    v[i].resize(3);
    v[i][0] = a;
    v[i][1] = b;
    v[i][2] = c;
 }


 return 0;
}
```

второй - использовать push_back.

Comment: Как я понял, сперва нужно зарезервировать память для n элементов в векторе, только потом, использовать их?

Comment: Не обязательно. Можно `v.push_back(vector<int>) ` в начале тела цикла и затем push_back элементы , как уже указали

Comment: не совсем. Есть вызов reserve, но он увеличивает capacity, но не размер. Поэтому правильнее - вначале увеличить размер до нужного, а потом можно обращаться по индексу или добавлять через push_back. Это не php или javascript.